# Volume of $K = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq x_3 \wedge x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \leq 1 \}$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I wrote an exam and didn't really know how to answer this question which gave $13$ points.

Let

$$K = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq x_3 \wedge x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 \leq 1 \}$$

Determine the volume $V$ of the set $K$ (till including the bounds of integration).

I only knew that

$V = \int_K dx$

But I have no idea how one needs to calculate this and I don't know how to write this in Wolfram Alpha either.

It would be awesome if someone could show how it's done because our professor doesn't provide solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $K$ is the region in $\Bbb R^3$ below the paraboloid ${x_1}^2+{x_2}^2=x_3$ and inside the sphere ${x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2=1$.

You can find the volume of $K$ by subtracting the volume of the region above the paraboloid and within the sphere from the volume of the sphere. (Call this region $K'$.) The sphere has radius $1$ so its volume is $\frac{4\pi}3$.

The volume of $K'$ can be computed in cylindrical coordinates:

$$\iiint_{K'}\mathrm dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{(-1+\sqrt5)/2}}\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

where the upper limit for the integral with respect to $r$ comes from the intersection of the sphere and paraboloid,

$$x^2+y^2=z\implies x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)^2=1$$

(Substitute $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and this reduces to the quartic $r^4+r^2=1$; the upper limit is one solution.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still don't really understand how you get to the upper limits for the integrals? Can you please elaborate on how you get to  $\sqrt{(-1+\sqrt{5})/2}$ and $\sqrt{1-r^2}$?

Comment: The limits on $z$ are straightforward. The points $(x,y,z)$ in $K'$ are confined by the paraboloid below, $z=x^2+y^2$, and the upper hemisphere, $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. So $x^2+y^2\le z\le\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. When converting to cylindrical coordinates, we take $r^2=x^2+y^2$, and the limits follow immediately from this substitution.

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates, the $r$ in $(r,\theta,z)$ corresponds to the distance away from the "origin" in some plane $z=\zeta$. ("Origin" here refers to the point on the $z$-axis in this plane.) We can bound $K'$ by a cylinder ([visual aid for your convenience](https://imgur.com/a/IiK6BKu)) of radius $r$ that contains the intersection of the paraboloid and sphere. Finding the exact value of $r$ is outlined in my answer.

Comment: By the way, WolframAlpha doesn't have robust support for multivariate integrals. That is to say, you can't have a query like "compute the volume bounded by the paraboloids $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=1-x^2-y^2$", but if you have the integral set up, you can write it out like so: [integrate 1, x from .. to .., y from .. to .., etc](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2C+x+from+-1%2Fsqrt2+to+1%2Fsqrt2%2C+y+from+-sqrt%281%2F2-x%5E2%29+to+sqrt%281%2F2-x%5E2%29%2C+z+from+x%5E2%2By%5E2+to+1-x%5E2-y%5E2)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the help. It'll take some time for me to understand it all, but I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With the cylindrical coordinates, the surfaces are $z=r^2$ and $r^2+z^2=1$. Then, the enclosed volume is

$$V=2\pi \int_0^a \left(\sqrt{1-r^2}-r^2 \right) rdr=\frac{5\pi}6a^4$$

where the radial upper limit is the intersection of the two surfaces, given by $a^2+a^4=1$, or $a^2={\frac{\sqrt5-1}2}$. The integral results in

$$V = \frac{5\pi}{12}(3-\sqrt5)$$

Comment: Thank you. How do you get to $a=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}2}$?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 - solve the equation $a^4+a^2-1=0$